# excluding xml tag in sed - specific case

Tags: xml, bash, sed, multiline

please help!
I have spend hours searching for my resoultion, and I am hitting the wall with my head...
All I want to do using sed is:
Find tag, which contains "Number Deleted" string, and remove it

input:

```
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s128"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s128"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s81"><Data ss:Type="String">Number Deleted</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s81"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s81"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s81"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s81"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s83"><Data ss:Type="String">-1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s81"><Data ss:Type="String">&quot;Deleted:&quot;</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s81"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s81"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s81"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Number Saved</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="5"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="7"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
```

output:

```
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s128"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s128"/>
   </Row>

   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Number Saved</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="5"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="7"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
```

so far I figured out, how to view xml exluding lines from "Number Deleted" till the end of the tag , but this does wrong for xml integrity, because  tag is not closed, here is what I have:

```
function filter_xml
{
  START="<Cell ss:StyleID="s81"><Data ss:Type="String">Number Deleted"
  END="<\/Row>"
  sed "/$START/,/$END/d" file.xml
}
```

Comment: You should use XML tools for this type of operation. Using sed or grep will fail on any complex nesting.

Comment: sure thing, that sed is not suitable, but kill me :) it has to be sed

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML-aware tool. For example, [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open file.xml ;
remove //Row[Cell/Data/text()='Number Deleted'] ;
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think `sed` is the best tool for dealing with XML files.

Couldn't you actually parse the XML file ?

Here is a some quick and dirty example with `python` :

**In /tmp/data file:**

```
<data xmlns:ss="foobar">
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s128"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s128"/>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
<Cell ss:StyleID="s81"><Data ss:Type="String">Number Deleted</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s83"><Data ss:Type="String">-1</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Number Saved</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="5"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
</Row>
</data>
```

**Python code :**

```
import xml.dom.minidom as Xml
file = "/tmp/data"
xmlDoc = Xml.parse(file)
for row in xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Row"):
  if "Number Deleted" not in row.toprettyxml():
    print row.toxml()
```

**Output:**

```
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s128"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s128"/>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Number Saved</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="5"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
</Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<Row /!b;:a;$bb;N;/.*\n[^\n]*<\/Row>/!ba;:b;/Number Deleted/d' file
```